# Glide: actualizar una imagen cuando actualizo la imagen en el servidor. Eliminar caché

Tags: java, android

Estaba trabajando con un ejemplo de un RecyclerView, en dicho RecyclerView, insertaba una imagen de un servidor web por medio de la URL de la imagen... Bueno al momento de instalar la aplicación todo bien se ve la imagen que tenia en el servidor web, pero al momento de actualizar la imagen en mi servidor, la imagen en mi aplicación no se actualiza. Tengo que borrar la aplicación e instalarla de nuevo para que se actualice la imagen. Me gustaría que la imagen se actualizara al momento cuando yo actualice la imagen de mi servidor.

**Código java de Actividad principal**

```
package com.herprogramacion.alquileres;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider.Contrato.Alquileres;

public class ActividadListaAlquileres extends AppCompatActivity implements     AdaptadorAlquileres.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private RecyclerView listaUI;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private AdaptadorAlquileres adaptador;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actividad_lista_alquileres);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Filtro...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Acción", null).show();
        }
    });

    // Preparar lista


    listaUI = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lista);


    listaUI.setHasFixedSize(true);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


    listaUI.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    adaptador = new AdaptadorAlquileres(this, this);


    listaUI.setAdapter(adaptador);


    // Iniciar loader
   getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actividad_lista_alquileres, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(AdaptadorAlquileres.ViewHolder holder, String idAlquiler) {
    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), ":id = " + idAlquiler,
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, Alquileres.URI_CONTENIDO, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (adaptador != null) {
        adaptador.swapCursor(data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
}
}
```

**Código java de Actividad Adaptador**

```
package com.herprogramacion.alquileres;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;



public class AdaptadorAlquileres extends    RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorAlquileres.ViewHolder> {
private final Context contexto;
private Cursor items;

private OnItemClickListener escucha;

interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onClick(ViewHolder holder, String idAlquiler);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    // Referencias UI
    public TextView viewNombre;
    public TextView viewUbicacion;
    public TextView viewDescripcion;
    public TextView viewPrecio;
    public ImageView viewFoto;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        viewNombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        viewUbicacion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ubicacion);
        viewDescripcion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
        viewPrecio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.precio);
        viewFoto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.foto);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        escucha.onClick(this, obtenerIdAlquiler(getAdapterPosition()));
    }
}

private String obtenerIdAlquiler(int posicion) {
    if (items != null) {
        if (items.moveToPosition(posicion)) {
            return items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.ID_ALQUILER);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public AdaptadorAlquileres(Context contexto, OnItemClickListener escucha) {
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.escucha = escucha;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_lista_alquiler, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    items.moveToPosition(position);

    String s;

    // Asignación UI
    s = items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.NOMBRE);
    holder.viewNombre.setText(s);

    s = items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.UBICACION);
    holder.viewUbicacion.setText(s);

    s = items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.DESCRIPCION);
    holder.viewDescripcion.setText(s);

    s = items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.PRECIO);
    holder.viewPrecio.setText(String.format("%s", s));

    s = items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.URL);
    Glide.with(contexto).load(s).centerCrop().into(holder.viewFoto);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (items != null)
        return items.getCount();
    return 0;
}

public void swapCursor(Cursor nuevoCursor) {
    if (nuevoCursor != null) {
        items = nuevoCursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public Cursor getCursor() {
    return items;
}

interface ConsultaAlquileres {
    int ID_ALQUILER = 1;
    int NOMBRE = 2;
    int UBICACION = 3;
    int DESCRIPCION = 4;
    int PRECIO = 5;
    int URL = 6;
}
}
```

**Código java de Base de datos sqlite donde inserto LAS IMAGENES**

```
package com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

import com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider.Contrato.Alquileres;


public class BaseDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final int VERSION = 1;

static final String NOMBRE_BD = "alquileres.db";


interface Tablas {
    String APARTAMENTO = "alquiler";
}

public BaseDatos(Context context) {
    super(context, NOMBRE_BD, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE " + Tablas.APARTAMENTO + "("
                    + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,"
                    + Alquileres.NOMBRE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + Alquileres.UBICACION + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + Alquileres.DESCRIPCION + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + Alquileres.PRECIO + " REAL NOT NULL,"
                    + Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN + " TEXT NOT NULL)");

    // Registro ejemplo #1
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Mis representantes");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Conoce a los posibles candidatos a la presidencia de México 2018");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¿Quiénes son?");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/misrepresentantes.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #2
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Elecciones");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Las elecciones federales de México de 2018, denominadas oficialmente por la autoridad electoral como el Proceso Electoral Federal 2017 — 2018...");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¡Enterate!");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/elecciones.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #3
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Reformas y leyes");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Enterate de las reformas federales vigentes asi como las proximas a tratar");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¿En que nos afectan?");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/reformasyleyes.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #4
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Noticias");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Noticias en tiempo real y anuncios clasificados de todo lo relacionado a las elecciones 2018");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "Mantente enterado");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/noticias.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #5
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Movilízate");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Enterate que puedes hacer por tu pais, movilizate!!!");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¿Por qué?");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/movilizate.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #6
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "¿Porqué participar?");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "No te preguntes qué puede hacer tu país por ti, pregúntate que puedes hacer tú por tu país");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¡Animate!");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/porqueparticipar.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #7
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "¿Quiénes somos?");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Somos una asociacion civil comprometida con nuestro pais, y el futuro que conlleva un nuevo presidente");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "Conócenos");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/quienessomos.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #8
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Ubica tu casilla");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "¿No sabes donde esta tu casilla? Enterate ahora!!!");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¡Qué no se te pase!");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/ubicatucasilla.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    try {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Tablas.APARTAMENTO);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // Manejo de excepciones
    }
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

**Código java del contrato con la estructura de la base de datos y forma de las URIs**

```
 package com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider;

 import android.net.Uri;

 import java.util.UUID;


 public class Contrato {

interface ColumnasAlquiler {
    String ID_ALQUILER = "idAlquiler"; // Pk
    String NOMBRE  = "nombre";
    String UBICACION = "ubicacion";
    String DESCRIPCION = "descripcion";
    String PRECIO = "precio";
    String URL_IMAGEN ="urlImagen";
}


// Autoridad del Content Provider
public final static String AUTORIDAD = "com.herprogramacion.alquileres";

// Uri base
public final static Uri URI_CONTENIDO_BASE = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTORIDAD);


/**
 * Controlador de la tabla "alquiler"
 */
public static class Alquileres implements ColumnasAlquiler {

    public static final Uri URI_CONTENIDO =
            URI_CONTENIDO_BASE.buildUpon().appendPath(RECURSO_ALQUILERES).build();

    public final static String MIME_RECURSO =
            "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd." + AUTORIDAD + "/" + RECURSO_ALQUILERES;

    public final static String MIME_COLECCION =
            "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd." + AUTORIDAD + "/" + RECURSO_ALQUILERES;


    /**
     * Construye una {@link Uri} para el {@link #ID_ALQUILER} solicitado.
     */
    public static Uri construirUriAlquiler(String idApartamento) {
        return URI_CONTENIDO.buildUpon().appendPath(idApartamento).build();
    }

    public static String generarIdAlquiler() {
        return "A-" + UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public static String obtenerIdAlquiler(Uri uri) {
        return uri.getLastPathSegment();
    }
}

// Recursos
public final static String RECURSO_ALQUILERES = "alquileres";

}
```

**Código java del encapsulador provider, encapsula el acceso a la base de datos**

```
package com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider.BaseDatos.Tablas;
import com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider.Contrato.Alquileres;



public class ProviderApartamentos extends ContentProvider {

// Comparador de URIs
public static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

// Casos
public static final int ALQUILERES = 100;
public static final int ALQUILERES_ID = 101;

static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(Contrato.AUTORIDAD, "alquileres", ALQUILERES);
    uriMatcher.addURI(Contrato.AUTORIDAD, "alquileres/*", ALQUILERES_ID);
}

private BaseDatos bd;
private ContentResolver resolver;


@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    bd = new BaseDatos(getContext());
    resolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
    return true;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ALQUILERES:
            return Alquileres.MIME_COLECCION;
        case ALQUILERES_ID:
            return Alquileres.MIME_RECURSO;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tipo desconocido: " + uri);
    }
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    // Obtener base de datos
    SQLiteDatabase db = bd.getWritableDatabase();
    // Comparar Uri
    int match = uriMatcher.match(uri);

    Cursor c;

    switch (match) {
        case ALQUILERES:
            // Consultando todos los registros
            c = db.query(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, projection,
                    selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            c.setNotificationUri(resolver, Alquileres.URI_CONTENIDO);
            break;
        case ALQUILERES_ID:
            // Consultando un solo registro basado en el Id del Uri
            String idApartamento = Alquileres.obtenerIdAlquiler(uri);
            c = db.query(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, projection,
                    Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER + "=" + "\'" + idApartamento + "\'"
                            + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ?
                            " AND (" + selection + ')' : ""),
                    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            c.setNotificationUri(resolver, uri);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("URI no soportada: " + uri);
    }
    return c;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                  String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Cuando actualizas te refieres a que cambias la url o el contenido manteniendo el mismo nombre.

Comment: Cambio el contenido, manteniendo el mismo nombre, desde el servidor. ejemplo la imagen se llama fruta.jpg y es una manzana, bueno ahora la cambio por una platano pero se sigue llamando fruta.jpg y en la aplicacion no se actualiza, se sigue viendo la manzana cuando ya cambie la imagen a un platano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que usas Glide, realiza `Glide.clear()` para limpiar el contenido del `ImageView` antes de cargar la imagen:

```
Glide.clear(holder.viewFoto);
  Glide.with(contexto).load(s).centerCrop().into(holder.viewFoto);
```

puedes tambin cambiar la propiedad para deshabilitar el cache, `skipMemoryCache(true)` :

```
Glide.with(contexto).load(s).centerCrop().skipMemoryCache(true).into(holder.viewFoto);
```

---

Otro método es agregar una firma diferente cada vez que carguemos la imagen :

```
Glide.with(contexto).load(s).centerCrop().signature(new StringSignature(UUID.randomUUID().toString())).into(holder.viewFoto);
```

Comment: Realice esto que me mencionas y no paso nada sigue igual sin cargar la imagen nueva. Lo que acabo de ver es que no ocupo des-instalar la aplicación para que cambie de imagen, también cambia la imagen si le borro los datos a la aplicación.

Comment: Claro porque vuelve a crear la estructura de la base de datos y borra el cache de la aplicación.

Comment: Jorge Alberto usa el método signature() y comentame los resultados, con este método aseguraria no cargar de caché la imagen anterior.

Comment: Que crack!, funciona a la perfección con el método signature, la imagen se actualiza al instante!, Gracias @Elenasys

Comment: Así es Jorge le asigna un id diferente que no encontraría en caché y obliga a actualizar la imagen dentro del ImageView, saludos!

Comment: La imagen es independiente a los datos, ejecuta el método onUpgrade() si no funciona agrega otra pregunta.